# django querysets in templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make specific queries by using some model entry fields.
I have the following model entry:

**models.py**

```
class Work(models.Model):

    categories =(
                ('cat1', 'cat1'),
                ('cat2', 'cat2'),
                ('cat3', 'cat3'),
                ('cat4', 'cat4'),
                ('cat5', 'cat5'),
                )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices = categories, default = 'projects')
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'works/thumbs', blank = True)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to = 'works/content_media', blank = True)
    published = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("work_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    @property
    def thumb_url(self):
        if self.thumb and hasattr(self.thumb, 'url'):
            return self.thumb.url
    @property
    def content_url(self):
        if self.content and hasattr(self.content, 'url'):
            return self.content.url
```

here is the view:

**views.py**

```
class WorksListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    model = Work

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Work.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-date')
```

and I am trying to query first by the category field then by entry in the following template:

**template.html**

```
{% for category in works_list.category %}
    <ul data-category-name={{category.name}}>
    {% for work in category.works %}
        <li data-thumbnail-path={{thumbnail.url}} data-url={{content.url}} >
            <div>
                <p class="gallery1DecHeader">{{work.title}}</p>
                <p class="gallery1DescP">{{work.description}}</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

what do I need to change?

Comment: For starters, [documentation for ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)  says "template will be rendered against a context containing a variable called object_list". So it seems that your template will not know what works_list is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, from what I can see there are a few problems. First, try adding `context_object_name = 'works_list'` That way you will be able to refer to the `object_list` as `works_list` like you do in the template outer for loop. The bigger problem is you are iterating over `works_list.category`, which according to your `Work` model is a `Charlist()`. I think you might be getting confused about what the `choices` kwarg does and expecting `{% for category in works_list.category %}` to iterate over your `choices` and giving you the list of cats you defined in `categories`. As far as I know, that's not how choices works.

If you go to your admin panel and add a new entry for your Work model, you'll see that category has a dropdown list that contains your list of cats. So, choices defines a set of legal category options for new Work objects, not a list in existing Work objects.

I think what you actually want is an additional model `Category` which defines: `work = models.ForeignKey(Work, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` as a one-to-many relationship. Basically, you want is for `Work` to have a subset of `Category` objects that you can iterate over. This will involve redesigning the way you structure and access your data though.

Comment: thanks @Sam. I got the context object part but could you show an example of how to change the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change at least your views.py and template.html. Add a context_object_name and an extra context([Doc Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context))

**views.py**

```
class WorksListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    model = Work
    context_object_name = 'work_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Work.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(WorksListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Insert categories so that it can be used in template
        context['categories'] = Work.categories
        return context
```

**template.html**

```
{% for category in categories%}
<ul data-category-name={{category.0}}>
    {% for work in work_list %}
        {% if category.0 == work.category %}
            <li data-thumbnail-path={{work.thumb_url}} data-url={{work.content_url}} >
                <div>
                    <p class="gallery1DecHeader">{{work.title}}</p>
                    <p class="gallery1DescP">{{work.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```